# add Strings and integers to Collection

Tags: java, string, list, collections, addition

i have implemented a interface and now i have to implement a method, where i have to add Strings and Integers into Collections.I tried c.add but it don´t work. Any ideas how i could do that?

Kind Regards.
E.C

```
public class AnswerList implements AnswerCollection {

private Collections c;

/* add String answer and mode to collection of answers and modes */
public boolean addAnswer(String word, int mode) {
    if(mode == LearnGUI.SOURCE_GIVEN){
        c.add(word);
        c.add(mode);
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `Collections` to `Collection`. Also you need to initialize it to some object (e.g. `ArrayList`). Also, don't use raw types.

Comment: Well,  what kind of Collection do you want?

Comment: *it don't work* is an absolutely useless problem description. If you don't understand why, call your auto repair shop and say *I have a Ford. It don't work. What's wrong?* and see if they can tell you without a whole lot more information.

Comment: Can i make an ArrayList without Generics?

Comment: You can also use instanceof to check the type of object before adding it to collection.

Comment: You can make collections without generics.  It's a bad idea.  Don't.

Comment: My example is one without Generics. It works but you have to be careful using its content further on. You have to check each element with the instanceof operator and you are forced to cast the object then from Object back to its actual type.

Comment: @DiabolicWords It's always better to make it explicit.  You're making a `List<Object>`, so you should declare it as `List<Object>`, even though this is exactly equivalent to `List`.  It's a readability and maintainability issue, not an issue of what actually works.

Comment: Having a string and an integer in the same collection is most often a poor idea (except if they are key and value in a map). Please rethink your design.

Comment: I agree with you. But the task was to help E.C to get both a String and an Integer in a Collection. And this was the easiest way by far.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is because Collections is no Collection in a programmatical sense!
Use a List instead. Do something like this:

```
List objectList = new ArrayList();
objectList.add(word);
objectList.add(mode);
```

Comment: There is nothing like HashList in java.

Comment: Sorry! My bad. Will correct it! Mixed up HashSet an ArrayList.

Comment: In what sense is it a collection? A collection of static methods?

Comment: Correct. It is a collection of helper methods that operate on Collections.

Answer (score 1):

The Collections class is a set of utility methods for working with Collections.  Generally, you want to add your items into a specific collection type.  You should look at the documentation for Collection and Collections.